# iMacros - Cannot get int only value using Number() from string

Tags: javascript, numbers, imacros

I have a problem with Number() function on **iMacros 9.0.3**

Here is my code:

```
result  = "USD 0.94USD 0.94(+94.00%)";
j       = 0;
length  = 0;
while (result[j] != "(") {
    length++;
    j++;
}
buff = "";
for (k=4; k < length; k++) {
    buff += result[k];
}
mains  = Number(buff);
jMains += mains;
if (mains > 0) {
    jWin++;
} else {
    jLoss++;
}
var num = jMains;
```

As you see at the above code, **buff** variable will contains "0.94USD 0.94", and i want to make it appears to "0.94".
But it just give me **NaN** result.

When i use **iMacros 8.9.7** it works fine for me. If it's a bug from **iMacros 9.0.3**, is there any other way how to trick something like that?

Comment: Use `parseFloat` instead of `Number`.

Comment: You can extract 0.94 with this: `hasil.split(/\w{3}\s/)[1]` instead of the loop

Comment: Thanks, parseFloat and split() is work, thanks a lot